# Call to a member function get_cart_contents_count () on null

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, cart

I have modified the email-order-details.php code to be able to include the total of items.

```
echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
```

This works well, except in one case.

When I modify several items, for example by changing the status from the Backend, I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_cart_contents_count () on null in email-order-details.php on line 61

Why can this error occur in the bulk edition? Is there a way to fix it?

Thank you!

Temporally solved with:

```
if ( is_null(WC()->cart) ) {} else { echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also use this line *(as **`WC()->cart`** is the live `WC_Cart` instance object)*:

```
echo is_object( WC()->cart ) ? WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() : '';
```

It should also work.

---

Now for the emails, **may be you are targeting "Order items" instead**. If it is the case you will need to get the `WC_Order` object… If you don't have it you can get it from the order ID…

```
// If the WC_Order object doesn't exist but you have the Order ID
if( ! ( isset( $order ) && is_object( $order ) ) && isset( $order_id ) ){
    // Get the order object from the Order ID
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 
}

if( isset( $order ) && is_object( $order ) ){
    $count = 0;
    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        // add item quantities to the count
        $count += (int) $item->get_quantity();
    }
    // Output the total items count
    echo $count;
}
```

This should better work this time…

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Always helping. My question is. Is there any way I can see the amount of items in the email when it is triggered by a massive update in the backend?

Comment: @jpussacq I have updated my answer, can you try it and give some feed back on it. Thanks